# $array[$key] = $something creates a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this php code that's supposed to check how many times a single item is in an array and put the amount in the value of that key.

im asking, why does the $duplicates[$item] += 1; create a new array instead of appending it to the existing array

[here](https://gyazo.com/d624947f4f0e50b954ebaa82d0095949) is the picture of the output I get.

this is my code:

```
$itemQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT cart_value FROM active_carts WHERE username=:prodName");
$itemQuery->bindParam(":prodName" , $uname , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$itemQuery->execute();
$itemCount = $itemQuery->fetchAll();
$arrax = $itemCount[0]["cart_value"];
$itemArrX = explode(",", $arrax);
$inQuestion = array();
$duplicates = array();
foreach ($itemArrX as $item) {
    if (in_array($item , $inQuestion)) {
        $counter = 0;
        if (!array_key_exists($item , $duplicates)) {
            $duplicates[$item] = $counter; 
            // doesnt even execute
        } else {
            echo $duplicates[$item]; // echoes a new array every time
            $duplicates[$item] += 1;
        }
    } else {
        array_push($inQuestion, $item);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what exactly are you asking?

Comment: updated the question @CaspainCaldion

Comment: There is still no question in your question.

Comment: yea thats a statement

Comment: im asking, why does the `$duplicates[$item] += 1;` create a new array instead of appending it to the existing array

Comment: here updated it again... sry

Comment: when you say create, then there are multiple instances of $duplicates, print the size of each addition and show me

Comment: Im gonna make a screen shot of what i get as the output, 1 second

Comment: I dont get it .. u may want array_count_values?

Comment: @mr.void i want to count how many items are duplicates of the same one..... example: product,product,something // outcome : $duplicates["product"] => 2

Comment: so you want array_count_values ;)

Look at examples: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: oh thanks i didnt know it existed!

Comment: @mr.void good suggestion, are you going to write up an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is rather simple, you never created that item in the array.

```
$data[$key] = $value; //examine that.
```

try this `$duplicates[$item] = $item;`
then `$duplicates[$item] += 1;`

Comment: $duplicates[$item] += 1; will always create a new array!

Comment: without creating one that is

Comment: `if (!array_key_exists($item , $duplicates)) {
        
        $duplicates[$item] = $counter; 

       } else {
                                                               $duplicates[$item] = $item;                                                                                                   $duplicates[$item] += 1;
        var_dump($duplicates);
       }`

Comment: aw it will? what do i do then? @caspain

Comment: $duplicates[$item] = $counter;  is not executed , you know why?

Comment: isset($duplicates[$item]]); use that , to check if that key is set instead

Comment: so check if the current key is not set in the duplicates array then create a new key, else index and increment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a count of duplicate values, I like the suggestion about `array_count_values()` in the comments. That can be run through `array_filter()` to remove the non-duplicate values.

```
$itemQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT cart_value FROM active_carts WHERE username=:prodName");
$itemQuery->execute([":prodName"=>$uname]);
$itemArrX = explode(",", $itemQuery->fetchColumn(0));
$itemArrX = ["foo","bar","baz","bar","boo","baz"];
$duplicates = array_filter(array_count_values($itemArrX), function($v){return $v>1;});
$inQuestion = array_unique($itemArrX);
print_r($duplicates);
print_r($inQuestion);
```

Or here's a condensed version of your code which should work just fine.

```
$itemQuery = $con->prepare("SELECT cart_value FROM active_carts WHERE username=:prodName");
$itemQuery->execute([":prodName"=>$uname]);
$itemArrX = explode(",", $itemQuery->fetchColumn(0));
$itemArrX = ["foo","bar","baz","bar","boo","baz"];
$duplicates = [];
$inQuestion = [];
foreach ($itemArrX as $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $inQuestion)) {
        echo $duplicates[$item];
        $duplicates[$item]++;
    } else {
        $duplicates[$item] = 1;
        $inQuestion[] = $item;
    }
}
print_r($duplicates);
print_r($inQuestion);
```